# 0.1 mm layer height print support material always fails to print

Tags: creality-ender-3, support-structures, layer-height, prusaslicer, support-material

Is there any way to increase the layer height of support material separately in Prusaslicer? When I add some supports to a model with 0.1 mm layer height, the support material also generates a smaller layer height which fails to print supports most of the time. I use an Ender 3 S1 printer.

Comment: It seems like currently there is no option to change supports layer height. Although, changing supports width may help in your case. You can try it under Print Settings -> Advanced -> Support Material.